# vueJS sort nesting table rows

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a json object list (carriers) like this:

[image: json data]

In my *.vue I render this with:

```
<tr v-for="carrier in this.carriers">
   <td>{{ carrier.id }}</td> ....
```

My thead / th's can be clicked for sorting the table like this:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th class="pointer link" @click="sort('id')">
         ID
         <span v-if="'id' === currentSortCol">
            {{currentSortDir ==='asc' ? '&#8593;':'&#8595;'}}
         </span>
      </th>
      <th class="pointer link" @click="sort('region.name')">
         Region
         <span v-if="'region.name' === currentSortCol">
            {{currentSortDir ==='asc' ? '&#8593;':'&#8595;'}}
         </span>
      </th>....
```

and my sort method is like this:

```
        sort(col) {
            if (this.currentSortCol === col) {
                this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
            } else {
                this.currentSortCol = col;
            }
            this.carriers.sort(this.sortBy(col, this.currentSortDir));
        },
        sortBy(property, order) {
            this.currnetSortDir=order;
            return function(a, b) {
                const varA =
                    typeof a[property] === "string"
                        ? a[property].toUpperCase()
                        : a[property];
                const varB =
                    typeof b[property] === "string"
                        ? b[property].toUpperCase()
                        : b[property];

                let comparison = 0;
                if (varA > varB) comparison = 1;
                else if (varA < varB) comparison = -1;
                return order === "desc" ? comparison * -1 : comparison;
            };
        }
```

**Problem:**
The sorting asc, desc is fine with the ID (carrier.id) . But it will not sort the nesting carrier.region.name column.
How can I sort a nesting column, like this carrier.region.name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like 'get' method from `lodash` package in order to get nested props:

```
import _get from 'lodash/get'
...
const propValueA = _get(a, property);
const propValueB = _get(b, property);
const varA = typeof propValueA === "string" ? propValueA.toUpperCase() : propValueA;
const varB = typeof propValueB === "string" ? propValueB.toUpperCase() : propValueB;
```

Comment: const propValueA = _get(a, property);
                const propValueB = _get(b, property);
                const varA = typeof propValueA === "string"
                    ? propValueA.toUpperCase()
                    : propValueA;
                const varB = typeof propValueB === "string"
                    ? propValueB.toUpperCase()
                    : propValueB; -- will work. can you update your answer, then I will accept it